# MySQL 5.6 Where is Show Master Status information stored

Tags: mysql, replication

I am looking for a way to pull the information that is returned from Show Master Status so that I can assign the File and Position values to a variable.

I was able to set slave_relay_log_info and slave_work_info to tables but that does not show the local Master information I need.

SHOW MASTER STATUS;

I am not sure what table holds the Show Master Status data.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.FILES`?

Comment: All the columns returned from that query are blank.

Comment: If it's stored anywhere, I'd expect it to be in the `mysql` database. But none of the tables there seem related to master/slave replication. So I suspect it's just not stored in any table.

Comment: Can't you just use the `SHOW MASTER STATUS` query itself in your application?

Comment: I need to be able to assign the File and Position values to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux bash script you can try below command through mysql client to store the File and Position in variables

**For File:**

`mysql -u username -p password -h IP -P Port -e "show master status" | grep "File"| cut -d ":" -f2`

**For Position:**

`mysql -u username -p password -h IP -P Port -e "show master status" | grep "Position"| cut -d ":" -f2`

Comment: Thanks, just one correction, need \G  after "show master status"  .   So :  mysql -u username -p password -h IP -P Port -e "show master status\G" | grep "Position"| cut -d ":" -f2

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL 8.0 the log file and log position are in the `log_status` table of the `performance_schema` schema:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM log_status ;
+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| SERVER_UUID                          | LOCAL                                                                                    | REPLICATION      | STORAGE_ENGINES                                           |
+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 506c04ec-815c-11ed-a962-0800272d3b77 | {"gtid_executed": "", "binary_log_file": "mysql-bin.000022", "binary_log_position": 157} | {"channels": []} | {"InnoDB": {"LSN": 36558461, "LSN_checkpoint": 36558461}} |
+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

The values can be extracted directly like this:

```
mysql> SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(`LOCAL`, '$.binary_log_file') AS file, JSON_EXTRACT(`LOCAL`, '$.binary_log_position') AS position FROM log_status ;
+--------------------+----------+
| file               | position |
+--------------------+----------+
| "mysql-bin.000022" | 157      |
+--------------------+----------+
```